# Android: align center image in TabHost

Tags: android, image, alignment, android-tabhost

I have made a custom TabHost and I want only images without text on each tab. How can I align the center of the tab my images? Any help please? Thank you. This is mi java code:
**JAVA**

```
private void cargarTabHost() {

        tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup(); 

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("mitab1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.borrar));
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("mitab2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("PLANO");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rllp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rllp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabs.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) {
        tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 75;
        tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title).
        setLayoutParams(rllp);   
    }

    TabWidget tw = (TabWidget)tabs.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

            View tabView = tw.getChildTabViewAt(0);
    tabView.setBackgroundResource(Modulo.cargarColorPestanas(perfilObj.getColor()));

    View tabView2 = tw.getChildTabViewAt(1);
    tabView2.setBackgroundResource(Modulo.cargarColorPestanas(perfilObj.getColor()));

    tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, I haven't tried but hope it works.

```
...
 for (int i = 0; i < tabs.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) {
        tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 75;
        tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title)
       .setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
...
```